Android Storage Access Framework (SAF): How to read file in internal file browser?
due to restrictions imposed by Google, I no longer have access to read all files in Android API 33+. I had presumed I could easily use Storage Access Framework (SAF) to list files within a directory selected by the user via "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE".
Here's how I attempted it:
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
m_OpenDocumentTreeLauncher.launch(intent)

I can access the directory and list all files within it into my internal browser like so:
val childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(rootUri))
val contentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver

val projection = arrayOf(
    DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
    DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
    DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_SIZE,
    DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE,
)

val cursor = contentResolver.query(childrenUri, projection, null, null, null)
if (cursor != null)
{
   try
   {
       while (cursor.moveToNext())
       {
           val docId = cursor.getString(0)
           val name = cursor.getString(1)
           val size = cursor.getLong(2)
           val mimeType = cursor.getString(3)

           fileList.add(rootUri.authority.toString(), docId, name, size, mimeType)
        }
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close()
    }
}

RootUri is the Uri of the selected directory via ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.
docId is the ID of the selected file.
And loading this file something like this:
        val documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(fileList.authority, fileList.docId)
        val contentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(documentUri) 

The Uri for the file I get in this example is:
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/9C35-6BCD%3ATest%2FTestFile.txt
So far, so good. Now, when I attempt to click on this file from to load its content into a FileStream, I encounter an issue. I consistently receive the error:
"Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/9C35-6BCD%3ATest%2FTestFile.txt from pid=22147, uid=10488 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs"
I had assumed that I would have access to files in this directory selected by the user via "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE". Is this not the case? How can I open/read a file in this folder without resorting to "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT"? I prefer using my internal browser for its ease and speed, as well as for a better user experience. Is this functionality no longer possible, or is there an alternative approach? Thank you!

There are some locations that are not granted under ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. You can find them here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions. If your test file is not in one of those, can you include the code where you read the file?

It doesn't matter which directory I choose. I always get the same error. It seems that it's not allowed to open a file even if the user gives permission to the directory with saf.

Are you using contentResolver.openInputStream() to open the file?

I already tried this. It doesn't work. I don't use action_document_open. I just listed the files in my custom browser and want to load them and get the permission denial.

You did not show how you obtained a content scheme for the files.

What do you mean exactly? I just go through cursor result and save the uri of each file in a list. After that when clicking on a file, i try to read the file with contentResolver.openInputStream(). Do I need additional steps to get access to the file?

You are not showing how you get uries from the cursor.

I ask because your file content scheme does not look ok. And of course you should be able to read all files.

I prefer using my internal browser Please talk about your own file explorer instead as a brower is for internet access. You confused me.

I meant an internal FILE browser. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit my question with more code in few minutes...

val fileUri: Uri = Uri.parse(fileUriName) We have no idea what you do here as nowhere there was a fileUriName. Please understand that you have to show us how you obtain your content scheme.

fileList.add(docId,... Please before that line put code that determines the content scheme for the file. It is irrelevant that you put all that stuff in a list. Show us how you obtain a content scheme.

You are right, I have edited the question again, I hope its more clear now.

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) Remove that line. It serves nothing and is only confusing for people why try to learn saf.



val documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(fileList.authority, ....


You cannot use that function.
Instead use
val childUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(rootUri, docId)

And see that the obtained content scheme is completely different.

Yes, this was the mistake! Thank you very much! Works perfect and also fast although saf is used.

SAF is only slow if you use DocumentFile. DocumentsContract is about as fast as classic File class.

Do you know if the permission for the folder persists after restarting the app? It seems like it does, but I thought I need to add a flag or something. Or maybe it's only like this in newer Android versions? I personally have Android 9. Or is there something else I need to consider with newer Android versions? I only know, that you can´t select root directory or download-folder or some other folders in newer Android versions.

You should take persistable uri permission directly when you get the root uri. Only then you can restart your app.

OK, I will change this:
val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
Thanks!
